# Trigger $stateChangeError on custom error thrown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using UI routing in angular application.
Each state is checked for authorization. In case of authorization a custom error is thrown. I want `$stateChangeError` to handle any custom error thrown from `$stateChangeStart`.

**`$stateChangeStart`**

```
 $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState) {
      $log.info("Route change start from", fromState.url, "to", toState.url);
       $rootScope.isAuthorized = authorize(toState);

          if ($rootScope.isAuthorized) {
            $log.info('is Authorized')
          } else {
            $log.info('not Authorized');
            throw new AuthorizationError()
          }
        });

    });
```

**Custom Error**

```
  function AuthorizationError(description) {
      this.message = "Forbidden";
      this.description = description || "User authentication required.";
    }
    AuthorizationError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);
    AuthorizationError.prototype.constructor = AuthorizationError;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys got the solution. I'm broadcasting the `$stateChangeError` from `AuthorizationError` itself. This is just a work around, i'll post the answer if there any other way to achieve this( other than rejecting `deferred` in `resolve` of the `state`)

```
function AuthorizationError(description, code) {
      this.message = "Forbidden";
      this.description = description || "User authentication required.";
      this.code = code || 'NOT_AUTHENTICATED';
      $rootScope.$broadcast('$stateChangeError', $rootScope.state.to, $rootScope.state.toParams, $rootScope.state.from, $rootScope.state.fromParams, this);
    }
```

**`rootscope.state`**

```
var transitionTo = $state.transitionTo;
$state.transitionTo = function(to, toParams, options) {
      var from = $state.$current,
        fromParams = $state.params;

      to = to.name ? to : $state.get(to);

      $rootScope.state = {
          to: to.self,
          toParams: toParams,
          from: from.self,
          fromParams: fromParams,
          options: options
        }

           return transitionTo(to, toParams, options)
        })
      }
    }
```